# How to release memory when wkwebview is closed

Tags: swift, memory, wkwebview

the code is there
[the WKWebview memory demo](https://github.com/DuckDeck/WKWebViewMemory)

I am working on a keyboard extension project and need integrate WKWebview . but when I close the WKWebview, the memory is not released,

[image: open webview]

[image: Close the webview and memory not release]

I want the system or webview release the memory immediately，because the keyboard extension only have 66m memory limit.

Here is the code I try to solve this issue：

```
  URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
  URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
  URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0

 //set WKWebViewConfiguration
  config.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()

 //deinit
deinit {
        webView.uiDelegate = nil
        webView.navigationDelegate = nil
        webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress")
       webView.configuration.userContentController.removeAllUserScripts()
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

WKWebview was load in WebKit process, the memory is not calculate to app, so  app memory not indicate the webview memory, instrument Activity Monitor can be usefull.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any source or link to documentation about this ?

Comment: Just search "difference between WKWebView and UIWebView", it's easy to get the result. If no result I can search for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).